# Powershell - The Parameter "XXXX" is declared in parameter-set "__AllParameterSets" multiple times

Tags: powershell

First of all, i'm sorry if this question has been posted before.
I couldn't seem to find and answer we could work with, so here goes..

Backstory:
Every 90 days all password of the NT-accounts will expire.
The office staff gets a notification when they're signing in into Windows 10.

However our iPad users (salesmen and technicians who are on the road) don't get a notification about the expiration.
They use an app which requires a NT-account to sign into our sales system.

Now we've found a Powershell script which would e-mail the user about the expiration of his password, but unfortunately we keep getting the following error:

> "The parameter "testing" is declared in parameter-set "__AllParameterSets" multiple times."

As we do not have any Powershell programming skills, we have no idea what going wrong in the script.

Could you guys help us?

The following script is being used (ofcourse edited with our SMTP server and e-mail addresses).

> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Password-Expiry-Email-177c3e27

Much obliged :-)

Comment: It would be better to ask your question in the `Q and A` tab of the scripts page on TechNet.

Comment: If you whittle the script down to an  [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it here, someone may be able to help.

Comment: the example script you linked to DOES NOT USE the word "ParameterSetName" anywhere at all. [*grin*] ... so, please, post the code that is actually generating the error msg.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey; Well, that actually _is_ the script we're using.

The script we're using can be found here:https://drive.google.com/open?id=10Fo49_s_qe2od776GmwWn8zDm8oBWuls

Note: I've deleted our SMTP and e-mail address. Everything else is untouched

Comment: @JelleOuwehand - take a look at my answer, please, [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

the code you 1st linked to never, EVER mentions parameter sets. not once. [*grin*]

the code in your 2nd link mentions it @ 106 = `__AllParameterSets`.

- that it IS NOT a parameter set attribute, but is some "other thing". it looks like a call to something in python.
- there is no other mention anywhere in your linked code of that `__AllParameterSets` thing.

so, the fix is to remove it OR to rename it something that does not use a powershell keyword. [*grin*]